# What am I doing wrong in this inequalities problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$\left|\frac{x^2} {x-1}\right|\leq 1$$

*In the case where $x>1$, there are no real roots.*

So in the case where $x<1$:

**I opened the L.H.S. with a $-$ sign** (as the modulus function has to remain positive).
After this **I multiplied both sides** of the inequation **by $-1$** giving me:
$\frac{x^2}{x-1} \geq -1$ [The inequality sign flips due to multiplication with a negative number].

What have I done wrong, as doing this led me to the wrong answer...

Comment: You did nothing wrong so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said $x>1$ is not possible so suppose $x<1$ then

$$
\left|\frac{x^2}{1-x}\right|=\frac{x^2}{1-x}\leq 1
$$

So if you rearrange this you get $x^2+x-1\leq 0$. Using quadratic formula you get $\frac{-1-1\sqrt{5}}{2}<x<\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

With what you are doing steps are following

$$
\frac{x^2}{x-1}\geq -1 
$$

Multiply both sides with $x-1<0$ then inequality change its sign again and

$$
x^2\leq -x+1
$$
which yields the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I realized the mistake.